# В массиве исключить ввод строк пользователем

Tags: javascript

```js
while (true) {
  var UserDigit = prompt('Введите числа через запятую ');
  var arr = UserDigit.split(",")

  var sum = 0;
  var work = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(arr[i])
    work *= parseInt(arr[i])
  }
  if (!isNaN(arr[i])) {
    alert('Вы ввели не корректные данные. Повторите,пожалуйста,ввод', '')
  } else if (isNaN(arr[i])) {
    break
  } else {
    alert('Error')
  }

}
document.write('Сумма чисел равна: ' + sum + '<br>')
document.write('Произведение чисел равно: ' + work + '<br>')
document.write('Среднее арифметическое равно: ' + sum / 2 + '<br>')
```